# What is the best current low cost way to run old PC software on ARM Macs

Tags: macos, windows, apple-silicon, wine

I would like to be able to run some old Windows and/or DOS games and applications on my M1 Mac.  If I have an .exe file that would run on an Intel mac using Boxer or Wine, what's the best low-cost solution for an M1 Mac?  I can't afford Parallels or equivalent for this.  I don't want to reboot into a different drive to achieve this.

Wine and [WineBottler](https://winebottler.kronenberg.org/downloads) do not appear to work.

When I try to install them, Wine will not copy over to my Applications folder.  Does Wine work with M1 Macs? It's not mentioned explicitly on [their site](https://winebottler.kronenberg.org/downloads), but `https://wiki.winehq.org/ARM` .

Is there a solution involving running QEmu, installing Linux and running an emulator inside Linux?  Is this realistic, or is the performance unacceptable?  I'm not planning to run high-end graphics here - just some old abandonware or equivalent.

Comment: i'm sure someone will come up with a comprehensive answer, hence just a comment - afaik, Windows [on ARM] 11 inside a VM like Parallels is the only way. It contains X86 emulation; the Mac does not, neither does any current Virtual Machine. They are hypervisors not emulators.

Comment: Not fussed whether it's a hypervisor, simulator, or emulator, just want something that works and doesn't cost a fortune!  Saw what looks like a v complex method here, using QEmu - https://randomblock1.com/blog/qemu-windows-mac/

Comment: My son runs an M1 with Parallels and uses it to support various Windows programs for university - simulations etc for engineering, not Word...

Answer (score 2):

The best and most low cost way is to use `qemu`. You do not need to install Linux - you can use `qemu` directly to emulate an Intel-compatible CPU in order to run your old DOS programs.

Whether or not the performance is acceptable is very subjective. It also depends a lot on what you think is "old PC software" - i.e. is it Digger from 1983 or is it Quake from 1996?

An easy way to get `qemu` running, if you do not want to start it from the Terminal, is to use the free software UTM:

https://mac.getutm.app/

Comment: And the easy way to run qemu is use UTM.app https://mac.getutm.app/gallery/

Comment: This is really helpful thank you! It says folder sharing is unreliable in Windows XP. I haven’t managed to get it working. Any idea how to make an ISO disk image on the Mac that XP will be able to read?

Comment: If anyone else is trying this, using an .iso of the Opera browser outlined in this  youtube video worked to allow me to transfer files from the web into Windows XP: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CTT5eMKvNVc&t=509s&ab_channel=Jack

Answer (score 1):

I have used [DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com) on Intel Macs to run old PC software. I do not have a M1 Mac, so I will answer based on the article titled [*"Apple Silicon M1: How to Run DOS Games and Apps"*](https://nomadic-dmitry.medium.com/apple-silicon-m1-how-to-run-dos-games-and-apps-b5858e51e339).

There is a fork of the DOSBox project called [DOSBox-X](https://dosbox-x.com), which supports Intel-based and ARM-based Macs. According to the article, there are two variations available.

- Native binary compiled for Apple Silicon processors. The release for ARM64 can be downloaded from [GitHub](https://github.com/joncampbell123/dosbox-x/releases). A link to download the same macOS ARM64 version can also be found on the [DOSBox-X](https://dosbox-x.com) home page.
- Native binary compiled for x86_64 processors, which means it will run through Rosetta 2 translation layer. This can be installed through using the [HomeBrew](https://brew.sh) package manager:

  ```
   brew install — cask dosbox-x
  ```